# Can i use Static Maps API V2 with Android and use it like JavaScript apiV3?

Tags: android, caching, google-maps-api-3, android-maps, google-maps-static-api

I am working on Google Map Api for Android. Its quite slow as network here is GPRS. I am trying to explore Static Map Api for performance (and offline usage). I am unable to find any example/sample on the internet where there is interaction of Static Map Api and Android. Google dont allow you to cache data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the static map api terms specifically prevent you from using it for a dynamic map. However, you could load the JavaScript Maps API in a WebView.